# 'apt install' fail to install a valid package

Tags: apt

I downloaded the vscode  to the  Downloads

```
me@host:~$ ls Downloads/code_1.31.1-1549938243_amd64.deb 
Downloads/code_1.31.1-1549938243_amd64.deb
```

Install it with apt , it prompt that unable to locate

```
me@host:~$ sudo apt install Downloads/code_1.31.1-1549938243_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Downloads
```

The package is in good condition Since I finally install it using gnome gui.

What' s the problem with my usage of ap install ?

Comment: If you want to install a locally downloaded deb package, you can install it using dpkg. `sudo dpkg -i packagename`. If you want to install it using apt, try giving absolute path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html), in the paragraph about `install`:

```
A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by following the
package name with an equals (=) and the version of the package to select.
Alternatively the version from a specific release can be selected by following the
package name with a forward slash (/) and codename (jessie, stretch, sid ...) or suite
name (stable, testing, unstable).
```

So `apt` treats `Downloads` as package name, since it is a perfectly fine name for a package, and the rest as the target. To make apt treat it as a path, the path must begin with something that cannot be a package name, like `.` or `/`:

```
$ sudo apt install Downloads/bash*.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Downloads
```

With a leading `.`:

```
$ sudo apt install ./Downloads/bash*.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'bash' instead of './Downloads/bash_4.4.18-1ubuntu1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb'
bash is already the newest version (4.4.18-1ubuntu1~16.04.york0).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
```